# Sending luggage to the hotel from Frankfurt Airport

Tags: luggage, germany, frankfurt

I wish to ship some luggage from Frankfurt airport to the hotel. I checked DE Bahn, it takes five working days. Are there other companies that can ship faster?

Comment: Do you mean shipping like you'd arrive at Frankfurt airport, pick up your luggage, hand it to some company, and they'll take it to your hotel in Frankfurt for you while you do other things?

Comment: You way want to ask your hotel. Or taxi companies maybe. Too bad Uber no longer operates in Frankfurt, that's the kind of thing drivers would have done.

Comment: It's exactly the thing taxi drivers do regularly

Answer (score 2):

I checked the webpage of DE Bahn because I found it odd that they would pick up luggage at the airport and I couldn't find the service you describe.

They offer an airport service where they ship your luggage to the airport and store it there for you to pick it up, and they have a cooperation with the German courier company "Hermes" which is described [here](https://www.bahn.de/hilfe/view/pk/en/gepaeck.shtml).

You are probably referring to the latter. But I am pretty sure they don't pick it up at the airport on their own because the service is designed to collect your luggage at home or your company and deliver it **to**  the airport or your destination before you actually arrive there.

The former seems to be a cooperation with the Luggage service of Frankfurt Airport where they store luggage for you up to 3 months and if you want to send it back to you.

Check the website of the luggage service [here](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/travel/services.detail.suffix.html/article/travel/luggage/storage.html#storage).